# Restoring a database into a different instance of tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have got most of the way but there seems to be a permissions issue somewhere:

Before the restore everything is working fine in my target environment - target has a server login account TCMDBUser which is mapped to my tridion_cm database user TCMDBUser

My source tridion_cm database has user TCMDBUser_DEV.

After restoring the source .bak into my target TCMDBUser_DEV is orphaned.

I edit the TRUSTEES table to correct MTSUser and my admin log accounts for my target environment and run the following to fix up my orphaned database user:

```
sp_change_users_login @Action='update_one', 
@UserNamePattern='TCMDBUser_DEV', 
@LoginName='TCMDBUser'
GO
```

I can log back in to Tridion explorer and see the expected list of publications and can walk through the tree structure but when I come to a folder which should contain items I see nothing with error:

and the corresponding event log error is:

```
Unable to get list of SDL Tridion Content Manager items.
DESCRIPTION

Error Code:
0x80040000 (-2147221504)

Call stack:
System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ConvertToFieldDictionary(IDataRecord,IDictionary`2)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.IdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Read(TcmUri,IDataRecord,IDictionary`2)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItemDataMapper.GetListItemsPost(IDataReader,TcmUri,OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItemDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.IOrganizationalItemDataMapper.GetListItems(TcmUri,OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItem.GetListItemsData(OrganizationalItemItemsFilter)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItem.GetListItemsStream(OrganizationalItemItemsFilter)
Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItemFacade.GetListItemsXml(UserContext,String,ListFilter,ListColumnFilter)
Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItemFacade.GetListData(UserContext,String,EnumListKind,ListColumnFilter,String)
Folder.GetListItems
```

Comment: Are you sure the database you restored is the exact same version as the SDL Tridion CM server you are connecting it too? And are the Collation settings of both Database servers matching?

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion this is a permissions error? I'm not seeing any kind of access check anywhere in the call stack...

Comment: @BartKoopman you've hit the nail squarely on the head - I have just confirmed that my source Tridion instance was not service packed but my target is. When I run the upgrade tool against the database and restart the error goes away. Inspired! Thanks and sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Chris mentioned, I always drop the user from the database and then assign the existing TCMDBUser in SQL Server the rights to the restored database. You can drop the user with the following command (on the restored database):

```
EXEC sp_dropuser TCMDBUser
```

Then through the SQL Server - Security - Logins, you request the properties of your TCMDBUser and in the User Mapping add the following database roles: `db_datareader`, `db_datawriter` and `db_ddladmin`.

That's what I've always done in the past and works for me, not sure if its all required, but worth a try I guess

Comment: I started from scratch and did the following: i) ran EXEC sp_dropuser TCMDBUser_DEV against restored db. ii) edited User Mappings for existing login TCMDBUser as suggested iii) restarted Tridion services - and the result is the same: no items in folders when in TCM Explorer

Comment: can you add some more detail on the actual error message in your question? also check the Tridion eventlog for that error and its details

Comment: I seem to have some kind of access as I can see and browse all the publications I expect to see and navigate through folders structure groups. But when I select a folder which I expect to have items in I see zero items. Event log error added to top of post.

Comment: Check the permissions on the items and organizational items tables. The user should have read and write permissions. I have seen this set wrong on binaries tables, but never seen your issue. Are you sure the user you are logged in as has permission to view the contents of that folder?

Comment: I am logged in as a Tridion System Administrator so read/write perms should not be relevant. I picked a Tridion sys Admin user at random from TRUESTEES table and changed their NAME field to my local user which worked as a valid login before I started the restore. Note also that I can for example view a publications properties.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to delete/drop the TCMDBUser_DEV form the DB and then create a new one with the same name and password (or reattach it to your cm DB). That should fix your problem.

I normally use the delete method with MS SQL server. I believe this occurs due to the ownership status that the TCMDBUser has on the database Schema.

When complete  your TCMDBUser  user should have the following permissions on your Tridion_CM database

[image]

Comment: Sorry getting confused between users and logins. My target SQL instance has a login TCMDBUser which I want to continue using as my user for access (preserving MMC snap-in settings), my restored database has an orphaned user TCMDBUser_DEV. Please can you list steps with T-SQL required?

Comment: I added a screen shot of the permissions above which may help

Comment: Thanks. yes that is how it looks. (I am rebooting server also to ensure proper ripple through)

Answer (score 2):

Try creating new user TCMDBUser in the database and run the following command

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Update_One', 'TCMDBUser', 'TCMDBUser'
```

Comment: Do you mean new user against tridion_cm or new login? I restored from scratch and created a new user TCMDBUser against tridion_cm and then ran the suggested script. Login to Tridion Admin gives same result as before. Surely I want to preserver permission carried over with TCMDBUser_DEV and tie it to a login user (which was my original post)?

Comment: I did as you suggested - created a new user TCMDBUser against tridion_cm and associated with existing login TCMDBUser. What do you mean login with admin user first? Can you detail steps required from db restore onwards please?